# I cannot get modules inside of modules to work when split across multiple files in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Related questions:

[My previous question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468451/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-classes-with-static-functions-versus-modules/13468894#13468894)

[My previous question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468166/can-i-declare-a-static-private-function-in-typescript/13468255#13468255)

I recently changed my code from classes with static methods to code that uses modules and exported functions. Here's an example of what I had before:

```
Inner 1.ts
/// <reference path="../typescript/reference.ts" />
module Outer {
    class Inner1 {
        static mvcOnFailure(message: string) {
            var a = 1;
        }
    }
}
Inner 2.ts
/// <reference path="../typescript/reference.ts" />
module Outer {
    class Inner2{
        static mvcOnFailure(message: string) {
            var b = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiled to .js without problem. I have one outer module called Admin and then inside that another module called Dialog and another called Grid. However when I tried to have private static functions I noticed that although there was a lock appearing next to the function in intellisense the function was not really private and could be accessed.  To solve this it was suggested to me that I should try using modules instead of classes so I coded as below:

```
Inner 1.ts
/// <reference path="../typescript/reference.ts" />
module Outer {
    export module Inner1 {
        export function mvcOnFailure(message: string) {
            var a = 1;
        }
    }
}

Inner 2.ts
/// <reference path="../typescript/reference.ts" />
module Outer {
    export module Inner2{
        export function mvcOnFailure(message: string) {
            var b = 1;
        }
    }
}

reference.ts
/// <reference path="../Outer/Inner2.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Outer/Inner1.ts" />
```

When compiled I have a huge problem as now each .js has all the
functions for everything that's in the outer module as below:

```
Inner 1.js

var Outer;
(function (Outer) {
    (function (Inner1) {
        function mvcOnFailure(message) {
            var a = 1;
        }
        Inner1.mvcOnFailure = mvcOnFailure;
    })(Outer.Inner1 || (Outer.Inner1 = {}));
    var Inner1 = Outer.Inner1;
})(Outer || (Outer = {}));

var Outer;
(function (Outer) {
    (function (Inner2) {
        function mvcOnFailure(message) {
            var b = 1;
        }
        Inner2.mvcOnFailure = mvcOnFailure;
    })(Outer.Inner2 || (Outer.Inner2 = {}));
    var Inner2 = Outer.Inner2;
})(Outer || (Outer = {}));
```

Is it time to give up on this idea as if I have parts of the same module with functions inside in more than one .ts file then it adds in everything in the .js.

Update:

Not sure about this. Now seems like the problem may have been related to my having installed web essentials. I disabled that and now I don't get the problem with functions from one file appearing in the java script of other files. Could this be related to the way web essentials does the compile on save. I read some place that the typescript should be compiled for all files at once and not just one file at a time. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you are having the same problem as Wouter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461758/referencing-typescript-file-includes-whole-file-in-output

Comment: @Steve - Thanks Steve. Yes it does seem like the same problem. I disabled web essentials, added in the line to compile before build that you suggested a while back and everything is now okay. Hope to get some confirmation about web essentials and then I could start using that again. By the way did you see my question about replacing classes with static functions with modules? Just wondering if you also think modules make a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: It depends. I would probably need a concrete example of what you were doing before I made my mind up on that. Generally speaking though it is modules and classes in TypeScript that give you code organisation.

Comment: @Steve - Here is what I am trying to achieve. I know it's only a small example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468451/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-classes-with-static-functions-versus-modules/13468894#13468894   All of this code is state-less. For example the opening of a dialog window or the attaching of events to controls on the web page.

Comment: I would say that as you have a function for a "normal" modal and a function for an "admin" modal, there is some room there for a general "modal" class with specialisations that inherit from it - rather than calling different functions to make it normal or admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow up to this, the TypeScript 0.9 alpha preview (which isn't stable, but is being worked on) contains changes to modules that should make it easier to define modules across multiple files.

From the [0.9 breaking changes wiki page](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9):

> The ‘module’ keyword no longer creates a type Description: In 0.9.0, a
>   clearer distinction is made between roles of namespaces, types, and
>   values. Modules now contribute only to namespaces and values and will
>   no longer contribute a type. Reason: This simplification of the role
>   of modules allow modules to now extend classes and functions more
>   easily.

This might help with your issue, but you'd have to try it to see if it does.